# I am getting a KeyError when flattening my JSON file. How do I solve this?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following list of dictionaries loaded from a JSON file:

```
data = [
  {
    'sales_id': 788,
    'company_name': 'Montreal_1',
    'order_details': [
      {
        'order_id': 988,
        'order_name': 'My Playstore',
        'external_label': None,
        'order_start_date': '2023-01-16T10:00:00-04:00',
        'order_end_date': '2029-01-17T23:59:59-04:00', 
        'associated_orders': [
          {
            'associated_order_id': 129,
            'associated_order_name': 'Yellow'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to flatten the list, up to the `associated_order_id` / `associated_order_name` level. This means I want to include all the data in the JSON template up to the `associated_orders` level.

Here is my intended output (the columns I need):

```
sales id |  company_name | order_id | order_name | external label | order_start_date | order_end_date | associated_order_id | associated_order_name
```

Here is what I use:

```
json_normalize(data, record_path = 'associated_orders', meta = ['sales_id','company_name',[['order_details','associated_orders']])
```

I get a `KeyError`

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: your `data` is not in proper list of dict. associated_order_name key name is not proper. missing closing ' literal.

Comment: Since `associated_orders` is nested in `order_details`, you should set `record_path = ['order_details', 'associated_orders']`. Other than that, I'm not sure what output you're actually looking for. You might add that to your question.

Comment: added intended output*

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put the complete path in `record_path`

```
json_normalize(data, 
record_path=['order_details','associated_orders'], 
meta=['sales_id','company_name',
['order_details','order_id'],
['order_details','order_name'],
['order_details','external_label'],
['order_details','order_start_date'],
['order_details','order_end_date'],
])
```

Comment: gives me a TypeError

Comment: Please update pandas to latest version. There is an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31507) with version 1.0.0

Comment: Yes I believe that was the issue.